# IE6 background appears-disappears on scrolling

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Given IE6, an UL-LI list and a background image for the UL container.

```
<style>
  ul {background-image: url(images/bgr.png);}
</style>
...
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

When I load the page, the background is randomly loaded, some parts are visible, some are not. Moreover, it changes on runtime when I'm scrolling on the page. When I scroll out the UL list and scroll back, different parts of the background will be visible, depends on the speed of scrolling.
Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a link? Can you reproduce it on another machine?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share it, but I'll make a naked sample. Other IE6s in progress.

Comment: I forgot the best :) The background also appears when I click on the StartMenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered similar problem some time ago (but it was simple background-color, without image) and if I remember correctly, adding `position:relative` to parent element solved this. So something like this:

```
<div style="position:relative">
 <ul>
  <li>...</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

IE6 struggles when it comes to using .png files full stop. There are various suggestions for fixes, but unless you have a specific reason for using a .png file (for instance transparency) I would suggest using a different file format. I've worked around it before by detecting when I have an early version of IE and substituting a .jpg for the .png file I wanted to use, so that most users with up to date browsers get a .png background but IE users get a .jpg.

Answer (score 1):

Does li float or something?
Try putting...
ul
{

zoom:1;
overflow:hidden;
display:block;
}

Answer (score 1):

height:1%;

You can use this to fix